# Sharepoint REST API to fetch groups nested within Groups (Transitive Members)

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Using the sharepoint REST API to fetch role assignments for a site:

`https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>/_api/Web/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member,Member/Users`

I have here a `Security Group` which nests another `Security Group` so im looking for something like `$expand=Member,Member/Groups`

^ The above API returns members the group is part of (rerverse than what is needed)

Note: Cannot use graph API here, should be the native REST API